# Grab a variable of a variable through strlen

Tags: php

Recently I have been having trouble making my function. I have been trying to limit the text of a string if it is too long. However, It doesn't work if I try to do it on a variable. For example, here's my function:

```
$test = "testasdfasdfsdaf";
function limit_text($text, $limit) {
if (strlen($text) > $limit){
$text = substr($text, 0, $limit - 3) . '...';
   }
   return $text;
   }

echo limit_text('$test', 10);
```

When I run the code, the only thing that comes up is $test. It doesn't grab the actual string of my variable $test. Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: I don't know php, but try replacing the last line with `echo limit_text($test, 10)`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `$test` as string to function here `limit_text('$test', 10)`

Change from

```
 echo limit_text('$test', 10);
```

To

```
 echo limit_text($test, 10);
```

Try Full Example

```
$test = "testasdfasdfsdaf";

function limit_text($text, $limit)
{
    if (strlen($text) > $limit)
    {
        $text = substr($text, 0, $limit - 3) . '...';
    }
    return $text;
}

echo limit_text($test, 10);
```

Comment: WOW! I'm so dumb. I wasn't aware the solution was this easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be :

```
echo limit_test($test,10);
```

remove `' '` from `$test`